# How can I get value in datetimepicker bootstrap on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My view blade, you can see this below :

```
...
<div class="panel-body">
    <order-view v-cloak>
        <input slot="from-date" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" title="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="from_date" id="datetimepicker" required>
        <input slot="to-date" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" title="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="to_date" id="datetimepicker" required>
    </order-view>
</div>
...
```

My order-view component, you can see this below :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <slot name="from-date" required v-model="fromDate"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
                -
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">                           
                <slot name="to-date" required v-model="toDate"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button v-on:click="filter()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                fromDate: '',
                toDate: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            filter: function() {
                console.log(this.fromDate)
                console.log(this.toDate)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I using v-model like above code

But, when I click the button, the result of

```
console.log(this.fromDate)
console.log(this.toDate)
```

is empty

It display empty

Why it does not work?

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind a slot using `v-model` and expect that `Vue` will attach that automatically to your slot input, but I can't see any reason why you need to use a slot here anyway. It looks like you just want an input that you can attach custom attributes to and you can do that by passing the attributes as a `prop` and use `v-bind` to bind them:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-bind="attrs" v-model="fromDate" />
    <button @click="filter">filter</button>
 </div>
</template>


export default{
  props: ['attrs'],
  methods: {
    filter() {
      console.log(this.fromDate)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fromDate: ""
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fromDateAttrs: {
      'data-date-format': "DD-MM-YYYY",
      title: "DD-MM-YYYY",
      type: "text",
      class: "form-control",
      placeholder: "Date",
      name: "from_date",
      id: "datetimepicker",
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can just pass your attrs as a prop in the parent:

```
<my-comp :attrs="fromDateAttrs"></my-comp>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvederzc/

**EDIT**

In reference as to how to create a date picker component, here's how I would implement a jQuery datepicker using `Vue.js`:

```
<template id="date-picker">
  <div>
    <input v-bind="attrs" v-model="date" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" v-date-picker/>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
  props: ['attrs'],
  directives: {
    datePicker: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        $(el).datepicker({
          onSelect: function(val) {
            // directive talk for 'this.$emit'
            vnode.context.$emit('input', val);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You can then bind that with `v-model` in the parent:

```
<date-picker v-model="myDate"></date-picker>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g64drpg6/

Comment: I try your jsfiddle. But, the datepicker not display

Comment: That's because I haven't attached a date picker, it's a proof of concept which you can use in your own code with whatever date picker you are using. I would have thought though, that a date picker should be a component that you can just add to your form with `<date-picker></date-picker>` which would be a neat solution.

Comment: Okay. Btw, My first code is not component. But, it is view blade. My second code which is a component

Comment: So your way could not seem implemented in my case. Because my first code is not component

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't use your component in your blade template, but here's how I would implement a jQuery datepicker component in Vue: https://jsfiddle.net/sphyv293/

Comment: You try see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230641/why-v-model-not-working-in-input-datepicker-vue-js-2. I update my question

Comment: remember `v-model` works on the `input` event, which your datepicker probably isn't firing, what datePicker are you using?

Comment: I using datepicker bootstrap

Comment: @BelminBedak Not sure how happy I would be to use a component with no tests and 37 open issues.

Comment: @craig_h your answer is pretty good, but seems like OP has sort of another issue with understanding some basic concepts in VueJS, and for him easier (not better) solution probably would be this component :) Just my 2c

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, I must use datepicker bootstrap

Comment: @craig_h, If using datepicker bootstrap, whether it can not be?

Comment: I've updated my JSFiddle for bootstrap-datepicker: https://jsfiddle.net/yznkdz82/

Comment: @craig_h, Thanks a lot. Btw, Whether it could use a bootstrap datetimepicker? I'm sorry. By that I mean before, I use datetimepicker bootstrap. No datepicker bootstrap :) It's diffrerent. I had update title of my question

Answer (score 0):

Cant expect any javascript technology to be complete before it becomes famous. Going by that, I tried all the recommendations from using `moment` to `vue-datapicker`. All recommendations heavily broke design and needed hardcode of the `div` `id`'s in the `vue` initialisation under `mounted`. Cant introduce hacks into my project this way. Messes up design and implementation neatness.

I fixed it using plain old jsp. On Save, I just did this

```
vuedata.dateOfBirthMilliSecs = $("#dateOfBirth").val() ;
```

I'll figure out conversion of date format to `milliseconds` in my java controller.