# Why v-model not working in input datetimepicker bootstrap? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component, you can see this below :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input v-model="fromDate" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" title="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="to_date" id="datetimepicker" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
                -
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">                           
                <input v-model="toDate" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" title="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="to_date" id="datetimepicker" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button v-on:click="filter()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return{
                fromDate: '',
                toDate: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            filter: function() {
                console.log(this.fromDate)
                console.log(this.toDate)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I select datepicker and click search button, it does not success to get value of datepicker

I try console.log, but the result empty

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get value in datepicker on vue component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228832/how-can-i-get-value-in-datepicker-on-vue-component)

Comment: Your code work fine for me - console logs inputs on button click.

Comment: @wostex, How can you try it? In my localhost, it does not display

Comment: @Potray, This question little different

Comment: I've just pasted it into my single file component and it does what intended. Is this just this component or may be your application is set up wrong? Try to replicate your problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42938177/392102

Comment: @Roy J, I'm sorry. By that I mean, I use datetimepicker bootstrap. No datepicker bootstrap. It's diffrerent. Btw, I had read your answer in the link. But  your answer are not accompanied by an example. So I find it hard to understand

Comment: The words "[wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)" link to an example. There are tabs to see the HTML and JavaScript.